# Exception in defer callback prevents iron-router from rendering when in an iframe on FireFox

Tags: javascript, iframe, meteor, iron-router

I'm working on Meteor app that mostly expects to exist within an `<iframe>`.

### Steps to reproduce

1. `meteor create iframe-test`
2. `cd iframe-test`
3. `meteor add iron:router`
4. `meteor`
5. Create a test page using jsbin.com or some other tool that loads `http://localhost:3000` in an iframe.
6. Load the page in Firefox and take a look at the console.  You'll see something like this (note you might need to hard-refresh with Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+R).

I've added links to an example jsbin and git repo below.

```
18:26:56.356 Exception in defer callback: onLocationChange@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?7b16fe70bccff9182aca02afb2ccd7708ac57c64:2227:55
Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:323:41
Tracker.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:207:41
Tracker.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:564:48
Router.prototype.start@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?7b16fe70bccff9182aca02afb2ccd7708ac57c64:2223:68
Router/ eval:23:19959
1 meteor.js:944:47
```

- The exception stops iron-router from rendering any template (the page just appears blank).
- Exception only occurs on *first load* - if you refresh the page using a soft refresh (Ctrl/Cmd+R) then templates get rendered correctly.
- The issue *can* be reliably reproduced with a hard refresh (Command/Ctrl+Shift+R)
- Exception only happens on FireFox (running 40.0a2) - fine in other browsers.
- Appears to be coming from the `Meteor.defer` call on line 44 of `iron-router/lib/router.js` (in the iron-router repository)

### Repro repos

- https://github.com/joeapearson/iframe-test (meteor app)
- http://jsbin.com/qucuberupi/edit?html,output (jsbin with an iframe)

Any ideas about what could be going on?

Thanks for any help!

For reference, I've reported this as a potential issue [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1381) although I'm not necessarily convinced the issue lies in iron-router itself at all.  I have a suspicion that this is somehow related to the HTML5 History API implementation in FireFox itself, which behaves differently in an `<iframe>` for some reason.

#### Workaround

Looks like it's possible to workaround this issue by dynamically creating the `<iframe>` before setting its location like this:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = 'http://localhost:3000';
```

Still think this is something related to how FireFox is setting up the HTML5 history in the `<iframe>`.  If you query `history.state` in the two differing iframes you get these results:

#### Dynamically created `<iframe>`

```
history.state // Object { initial: true }
```

#### Statically created `<iframe>`

```
history.state // null
```